# Filtering features outside features of another layer using QGIS geometry generator

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator, qgsexpression

I am trying to filter features in one layer outside features in another layer using geometry generator.

I have a buildings layer and an area layer and now I want to only show the buildings outside the areas.

The buildings layer is a polygon layer and the area layer is also a polygon layer consisting of several areas (features).

Since it is a many feature area layer I think I need to use an aggregate function e.g. `collect()` and/or `aggregate()` from the QGIS expression builder.

I trying the following expression on the geometry generator on the buildings layer...

```
difference( 
    $geometry, collect(geometry
                            (get_feature('layer_id','attribute','value')
                                )
                            )
                       )
```

...which ends up in an syntax error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if(disjoint($geometry,aggregate('area','collect',$geometry)) = 1,$geometry,NULL)
```

Explanation:

- `aggregate('area','collect',$geometry)` creates one single MultiPolygon out of your area layer
- `disjoint($geometry,MultiPolygonFromAreaLayer)` then checks if the current building is outside the MultiPolygon or inside. It will return `1` if its outside and `0` if its inside. If `disjoint()` does not meet your criteria, you can use `intersects()`, `within()`, `contains()`, etc instead.
- The `if()` statement then evaluates wheter the current geometry should be displayed (`$geometry`) or not (`NULL`). Depending on your usecase you can vary this.

[image]